# Upload image file errror after 19 images in php

Tags: php, android

I am using a php to upload multiple images around 30 or so. I have compressed the image to 100kb before uploading. When I try to upload images via Android then I don't get any error. Only 19 images are transferred to the server but not the rest. I am using cPanel shared hosting account and it's not a website only php.

How can I upload more than 19 images?

```
/////// images

if (!empty($images_names_str)) {


    if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
        $images_names_str = stripslashes( $images_names_str );
    }
    $newstr = json_decode( $images_names_str,true );


    $i = -1;
    foreach($newstr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
        $i++;

        $name = $item['name']; //etc
        $path = $item['path'];

        $file_path1 = "/home/public_html/images/";
        // Use
        if ($_FILES['image'.$i]['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            //uploading successfully done
            $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image'.$i]['tmp_name'], $file_path1.$name);
            fputs($fp,"File has been moved from to" . $file_path1.$name. "\n");
        } else {
            fputs($fp,$_FILES['image'.$i]['error'].$i." ERROR: File not moved correctly".$file_path1.$name. "\n");
        }
    }
    echo "done";
}
```

Comment: What does the php error log show? I am guessing that you might see something like `HTTP request length 134833 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072)`, meaning that you have attempted to upload more than the server wants to accept in one go. More information on this [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-mod_fcgid-http-request-length-exceeds-maxrequestlen)

Comment: I did not get any error.Am I doing anything wrong? How can I set the check ? I have tried the code above and it displays the default string itself but not the error reason.

Comment: `$file_path.$name.` If you upload 30 images they all will have a different name. You are not showing how you determine $name or how you send a name.

Comment: `it's not a website only php. ` ??? What do you mean?

Comment: `it displays the default string itself but not the error reason.`. Which default string? And what is printed for `$_FILES['image'.$i]['error'].$i`?

Comment: Its not website in the sense that I dont have any php.ini or .htaccess file out here.Also the error I got is : 20 ERROR: File not moved correctly/home/... And Images are sent in a json_array which is decoded and I have updated the code.

Comment: send a dump of vars: $newstr and $_FILES. you run this script in browser ?

Comment: No I am sending it from an Android device.